# SQL: Get the average value of stocks in each fund

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with the following information:

```
_______________________________________________________
|   fundName   |   stockName   |  numShares  |  price  |
_______________________________________________________
|   Sunshine   |     Enron     |     10      |   $5    |
|   Sunshine   |     Lehman    |     40      |   $10   |
|   Brightsky  |  BearStearns  |     20      |   $3    |
|    Pillar    |       GM      |     100     |   $30   |
|    Pillar    |    Chrysler   |     80      |   $22   |
|    Pillar    |    Bricklin   |     200     |   $2    |
```

I need to write a query that will return a table containing the name of all of my funds in one column, and the average stock value of shares in the fund. The average should be weighted, meaning if there are 80 shares of company A and 20 shares of company B in a particular fund, the average share value should be weighted 80% by company A.

For instance, for the above table, I'd like to get the result:

```
___________________________________
|   fundName   |   avgSharePrice  |
___________________________________
|   Sunshine   |         $9       |
|   Brightsky  |         $3       |  
|    Pillar    |       $13.58     |
```

Comment: What have you tried/written to get the answer you seek? Gotta show you've at least tried, otherwise people will think you're trying to get others to do your homework for you. :P

Comment: @MattD You're right, I should have but my queries were such a mess, and not worth much insight.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT fundName, sum(numShares * price) / sum(numShares) AS avgSharePrice  
FROM table GROUP BY fundName;
```

Comment: Great, it works! I didn't expect it to work though since it's working across so many different rows and columns at the same time - for instance, it's multiplying `numShares` and `price` from the same row, and then also summing `numShares` across the entire table for items of the same `fundName`. I didn't realize SQL can do things like this that require a sense of "order". 
Anyway, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Imray SQL is based on set-theory and logics,you may have a look [here](http://books.google.com/books?id=2hM3-xxZC-8C&printsec=frontcover&dq=Applied+Mathematics+for+Database+Professionals&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xaSoUo7HKoTAtQbpioG4Bg&ved=0CEcQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=Applied%20Mathematics%20for%20Database%20Professionals&f=false) if interested.

Answer (score 3):

```
select fundName , sum(numShares * price) / sum (numShares) avgSharePrice  
from stock_info
group by fundName
```

[**sqlfiddle demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/31970/1)

Comment: Thanks Mohsen! I accepted the first answer because it came first, but I really appreciate yours too. Khoda hofez! and please tell your leaders not to build nuclear weapons.

Comment: Dear @Imray thanks for the comment. We are trying every day to the target. Things are more complicated here. 'Shad Bashid'